# why ch1 == ch2 is false, doesn't it hold the same char values?

Tags: java, char, equality, primitive-types

I'm trying to compare two char primitives ch1 and ch2. Both are assigned the value 1 as shown below.

But when compared using the "==" operator it returns false, which I don't understand how or what's happening behind the scenes.

```
char ch1 = (char)1;
char ch2 = '1';
System.out.println(ch1==ch2); //false

//further comparisions
System.out.println(ch1 == 1);       //true
System.out.println(ch1 == '\u0031'); //false

System.out.println(ch2 == 1);       //false
System.out.println(ch2 == '\u0031'); //true
```

Comment: `c1 == '\u0001'`

Comment: To answer this, you need to understand how `char` is encoded, which requires you to understand the ASCII table. The character "1" is actually equal to `49`,  where as `1` is actually equal to `SOH` (or, "start of header")

Comment: ...and `ch2 ==' \u0031'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'1'` has the value 49 (31 hexadecimal).

`(char)1` has the value 1.

A `char` is just a 16-bit integer.  The notation `'x'` means 'the character code for the character x', where the encoding used in Java is Unicode, specifically UTF-16.

The cast `(char)` does not change the value of the expression to its right, except that it truncates it from a full-size integer to 16 bits (which is no change for values 0 to 65535).

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you are doing is casting the number one as a char, so `ch1` is now equals to unicode character 1 (SOH or Start of Header)

So when you compare ch1 (SOH) to ch2 ('1') its going to return false
As well if you compare ch1 (SOH - \u0001) to `'1' - \u0031 is going to return false

That's the main reason why is returning false, the unicode value of ch1 that you expect is different from the one you assigned

Comment: That;'s "Unicode character 1", not ASCII -- Java uses Unicode, not ASCII.  Yes, the encoding is the same for 0 to 127, but it's still Unicode.

Comment: Thx for the clarification, forgot about something really basic.

Comment: It's my pet peeve: Unicode is over 30 years old and people still talk of ASCII. I get a bit soapboxy about it  :-)

Comment: My pet peeve is that a `char` is not Unicode.  It can't even hold a Unicode codepoint.  Yet people still equate `char` values and Unicode codepoints :-)

Comment: @DavidValladaresL. I didn't know ```(char) 1``` would be taken as SOH, Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @StephenC - my other pet peeve is that Unicode burns codespace on nonsense like emojis. (Yeah, I know the 16-bit limit was looking like too small even without that, and  that emojis aren't in the BMP anyway. Such are the lessons of history).

Comment: @passer-by Unicode has a range of over a million code points, with only about 144,000 assigned. So we can afford to burn a few code points on emoji. But I do recall the original charter of Unicode restricted assignments to only real scripts, academically verified. Thus their refusal to include Klingon, Elvish, and other fictional languages/scripts. But now the Unicode Condortium throws in emojis by the dozens on every update. ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

## Code point

The `char` type is essentially broken since Java 2, physically incapable of representing most characters.

Instead use code point integer numbers. Every character is permanently assigned a specific number, a code point.

```
int codePoint = "1".codePointAt( 0 ) ;  // Annoying zero-based index counting.
```

The result is 49 decimal, 31 hexadecimal.

Make a string of that single character per the code point.

```
String s = Character.toString( codePoint ) ;
```

Or more specifically:

```
String latinDigitOneCharacter = Character.toString( 49 ) ;
```

As others pointed out, your code was mistakenly comparing the character defined as the Latin digit “1” with a code point of 1.

The character assigned to the code point of one is the [control code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes) SOH, Start of Heading. This is true in both Unicode and US-ASCII (Unicode is a superset of US-ASCII).